# Browser's need for NextJs hydration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I wish to understand if a browser is needed to perform hydration step in NextJs? In our use case we have a huge Json that needs to be hydrated causing performance drag on the browser.

Is it possible to have an intermediate server/layer that interface with client and on one side and Nextjs server on other and perform this hydration? Client receives the final HTML.

One may wonder why not simplify the code: We are creating a multi-tenant system and we don't know page structure statically. We fetch the page structure from backend and then use it Next layer.

**Request flow**

```
Client browser -> Intermediate server -> NextJs server
```

**Response flow**

```
NextJs server -> Intermediate server (hydration happens here) -> Client browser
```